# Unable to launch my app from Google Phone app contacts tab

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, intentservice, android-intent-chooser

When I was attempting to open My Contacts App via the Google Phone app Contacts tab but are receiving an error that there are no apps available to display the contact.

I appreciate any suggestions, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, This solution solved my problem, We need to add below `<intent-filter>` in manifest file of the corresponding `activity`.

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="YourAppPackageName.VIEW_CONTACT" />
                <action android:name="android.provider.action.QUICK_CONTACT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/contact" />
                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/raw_contact" />
                <data android:scheme="content" />
                <data android:host="com.android.contacts" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            </intent-filter>
```